# Protractor CCS Selector can't locate element on hidden toolbar

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, protractor

I'm clicking on a link that opens a new window with a PDF document. I switch to the new Window, which I verified that I was on by getting the URL. The window has a toolbar at the top which is visible for a few seconds when the window opens, and then hides itself unless you move the mouse again. I'm trying to click on the Download button, but anything I try gives an error that the CSS Selector can't find the element. I'm suspecting it's because of the nature of the animated toolbar, but I'm not sure. At first I was just trying a regular click:

```
element(by.id('download').click;
```

And that was not working. So I tried navigating the mouse to click on it:

```
browser.driver.actions().mouseMove(element(by.id('download'))).perform();
element(by.id('download')).click();
```

I've also tried selecting by css:

```
element(by.css('#download').click();
```

All give me -Failed: No element found using locator.

Could someone please tell me if what I'm doing is possible, and if so, how I might be able to accomplish it?

[screencapture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlYlg.jpg)

[Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LbF4.jpg)

Comment: Use browser.wait until the download icon is visible in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround than a solution, but what works for me with elements that are for some reason not visible (covered with other elements or working only on hover) is to just inject a script. Like:
`browser.executeScript(
      "document.querySelector('[id=\"download\"]').click()"
    );`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the query selector statement is creating a null and giving an error. Apparently it still can't see the element on the page. Just as a note, I can't even query the element in the console dev tool in Chrome.